# “Always stay on top” for WScript.Shell.Popup

Tags: vbscript, popup

I've got a windows shell popup that I need to always stay on top of other programs.  However, I also need `OK` and `Cancel` buttons on it as well.  If I use the `4096` method as shown below, I lose the ability to have my `Cancel` button.

```
intResult = WshShell.Popup(strMessage, intTimeout, strTitle, 4096)
```

If I use the following, then I am able to have `OK` and `Cancel` buttons, but I lose the ability to have the popup "always on top".

```
intResult = WshShell.Popup(strMessage, intTimeout, strTitle, 1)
```

Does anyone know how I can have the `Ok` and `Cancel` buttons and always keep the popup on top of other programs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does the job:

```
intResult = WshShell.Popup(strMessage, intTimeout, strTitle, 1 + 4096)
```